Dependency error on installing px4.bash
This the complete terminal text on installing PX4-Autopilot.
How can I solve the errors and succeed with the installation?
/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/setup/ubuntu.sh  

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo6 (= 6.2-0ubuntu2.1) but 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 is to be installed 

Depends: libncurses-dev (= 6.2-0ubuntu2.1) but 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 is to be installed

 libncursesw5-dev : Depends: libtinfo6 (= 6.2-0ubuntu2.1) but 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 is to be installed 

Depends: libncurses-dev (= 6.2-0ubuntu2.1) but 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 is to be installed 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 
```♤ 


Install the packages mentioned in the error messages, then retry. Lather, rince, repeat.

sudo apt install libtinfo6=6.2-0ubuntu2.1 libncurses-dev=6.2-0ubuntu2.1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. I have tried few times but I get that message several time.

libtinfo6 (6.2-0ubuntu2.1) looks like it belongs to the focal-updates repository while libtinfo6 (6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2) belongs to the noble repository - which suggests you have a mix of different releases in your sources.list and/or your sources do not reflect the information in the /etc/lsb-release file

it works. thank you so much.
Check your sources list for mixed or conflicting entries. Open /etc/apt/sources.list and files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with a text editor:
bash
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
bash
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
If you find any entries related to the "noble" repository or any other mismatched sources, consider commenting them out, for example, your sources should primarily refere
plaintext
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

This question is similar to: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages while installing libgl1-mesa-dev for qt. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It sounds like you have repositories from different Ubuntu releases mixed together, which can lead to conflicts between package versions. Here’s how to resolve this issue:

Verify your current Ubuntu version by running in a terminal:
lsb_release -a


Check your sources list for mixed or conflicting entries. Open /etc/apt/sources.list with a text editor (here nano):
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

and check the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ using:
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

If you find any entries related to the noble repository or any other mismatched sources, consider commenting them out (by adding a # at the beginning of the line) or removing them.

If your /etc/apt/sources.list is not aligned with your current Ubuntu version, update it to reflect the correct version. For Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa), for example, your sources should reference focal repositories:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


After adjusting your sources, update your package list:
sudo apt update


Upgrade your system to ensure all packages are aligned with the repositories:
sudo apt upgrade


Try fixing any broken packages with:
sudo apt --fix-broken install


Try to install the desired packages again:
sudo apt install libncurses5-dev


If you have third-party PPAs (Personal Package Archives), they might be causing conflicts. List them with:
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/




Dear Fatih, Welcome to StackExchange. Please try to format the source code in your answers by enclosing the code in backticks, e.g.,  `your text here`, or by indenting the code lines. See also format tools at the answer GUI.
